# How to declare kotlin Compiler Extension version using version catalog file

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I migrated my Gradle to Version Catalog and I want to move the Kotlin compose compiler to the libs.versions.toml as well.

This is my current declaration in the Gradle App:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.11"
}
```

I tried to do it like this

**libs.versions.toml**

```
[versions]
kotlinComposeCompiler = "1.5.11"
```

**build.gradle.kts (:app)**

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "${libs.versions.kotlinComposeCompiler}"
}
```

But my project sometimes doesn't sync with this error:

*Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:provider(?).*

What is the correct way to declare Kotlin Compiler Extension version using version catalog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've set up the version catalog correctly. This generates some code including a property `libs.versions.kotlinComposeCompiler` which is of type `Provider<String>` (click on it in your IDE to take a look).

[`Provider`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html) is a Gradle type which is a wrapper around the version designed to help with lazy initialisation, though that is not applicable here.

To get the `String` version you need from inside the `Provider`, you simply call `get()` on it, so you end up with:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.kotlinComposeCompiler.get()
}
```